# ANDROID/Univert.BA in bin/classes.dex

Tags: java, android, eclipse, virus

I was developing on an android project in eclipse and wanted to test it on my connected android phone. In that very moment Avira Free Antivirus told me that it found an `ANDROID/Univert.BA` virus in `bin/classes.dex` where `bin` is a directory in the project folder of my current project. Is this really a virus?

I deleted the `classes.dex` file an cleaned the project but every time I try to run the project the file is generated again and Avira again blocks access to that file.

Answer (score 1):

its false positif by anti virus
those are compiled soure code by eclipse, so its needed.

you can add exception in avira and add classes.dex to exception list.
or add whole android project as folder exception